# New and old jQuerys

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This script is at header, i need jquery-1.7.2.min.js for main.js to fancybox.js

[image: HEAD]

This script is at footer ,i need jquery-1.11-3.min.js for bootstrap.js and the two functions
So the question is how to use jQuery noConflict() when i'm using old fancy and light box and new bootstrap where do i need to put noConflict()  so that both jQuerys load and all js files load and  work

[image: BOTTOM]

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.mask.js"></script>




 <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.link1').click(function () {
        $(this).text(function (i, old) {
            return old == 'See Less-' ? 'See More+' : 'See Less-';
        });
    });
    $("#btnsearcg1").click(function () {
        $("#searchid").toggle();
        $(".mobile-logo").toggleClass('clickedm');
        $("#searchid").toggleClass('inline1');

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please include the actual code and not just images of it.

Comment: Recommendation: update main/fancybox, use newer jQuery everywhere. To 'correctly' use multiple jQuery versions the existing code will need to bind/closure over the at-that-point jQuery - which is a 'good practice', but isn't always done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the fancy box is being called in the top. You can leave it there and in the end of the page, after your custom script of see more and see less, you can call jQuery no conflict by:

```
$jq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

And I hope this should return the handle of the old jQuery back and if you wanna use the new one, you need to use `$jq` for this! I had the same issue with Drupal 7 and I fixed it this way!

Comment: You helped a lot fount solution,

Comment: jQuery and bootstrap and top then old jQuery and fancy box ,man.. and at the end of code loaded my custom script. Ty a lot.